# NoReverseMatch at /info/1

Tags: python, django

весь день пытался понять почему выдаёт ошибку:
**NoReverseMatch at /info/1
Reverse for 'like_book' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['like/(?P[0-9]+)\Z']**

views.py

```
def LikeView(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(BookModel, id=request.POST.get('book_id'))
    book.likes.add(request.user)
    return redirect('more_info', pk=pk)
```

html

```
<form action="{% url 'like_book' book.pk %}" method='POST'>
           {% csrf_token %}
           <button type="submit" name="book_id" value="{{ book.id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Like</button>
       </form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', index, name='index'),
   path('allbook', AllBookView.as_view(), name='allbook'),
   path('addbook', AddBookView.as_view(), name='addbook'),
   path('register', RegisterView.as_view(), name='reg'),
   path('login', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
   path('logout', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
   path('info/<int:id>', MoreInfoView.as_view(), name='more_info'),
   path('profile', profileview, name='profile'),
   path('password-change', ChangePasswordView.as_view(), name='change_pass'),
   path('like/<int:pk>', LikeView, name='like_book')


]
```

Comment: Текст ошибки намекает, что ошибка происходит внутри MoreInfoView, значит покажите нам MoreInfoView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если измените эту строку вот так. Будет работать?

```
book = get_object_or_404(BookModel, id=pk)

и тут вот так redirect('more_info') без pk=pk
```